# Can't properly assign object when subscribing to observable

Tags: angular, typescript

I seem to be having a problem with assigning an object to json data. I guess I'm having a hard time with creating interfaces that contain an array.

Here is my interface:

```
interface QAmount{
    read: string;
    amount: number;
}

export interface FRow{
    AmountName: string;
    AttachedAmount?: QAmount[];
}
```

In my component I'm subscribing to that observable in the constructor as so:

```
newData: FRow[];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.jsonService.getData().subscribe(data => {
      this.newData = data;
      console.log(data);
    })
  }
```

The returned data that is shown in the console.log is:

```
basic: {2019-1: "7,672", 2018-2: "7,698", 2019-3: "7,679", 2018-4: "7,706"}
basic $: {2019-1: "1.15", 2018-2: "$0.96", 2019-3: "$3.39", 2018-4: "$1.00"}
cost of revenue:: ""
diluted: {2019-1: "7,744", 2018-2: "7,794", 2019-3: "7,759", 2018-4: "7,798"}
diluted $: {2019-1: "1.14", 2018-2: "$0.95", 2019-3: "$3.36", 2018-4: "$0.99"}
earnings per share:: ""
general and administrative: {2019-1: "1,179", 2018-2: "1,208", 2019-3: "3,460", 2018-4: "3,483"}
gross margin: {2019-1: "20,401", 2018-2: "17,550", 2019-3: "59,628", 2018-4: "51,664"}
income before income taxes: {2019-1: "10,486", 2018-2: "8,641", 2019-3: "31,092", 2018-4: "25,794"}
net income $: {2019-1: "8,809", 2018-2: "$7,424", 2019-3: "$26,053", 2018-4: "$7,698"}
operating income: {2019-1: "10,341", 2018-2: "8,292", 2019-3: "30,554", 2018-4: "24,679"}
other income, net: {2019-1: "145", 2018-2: "349", 2019-3: "538", 2018-4: "1,115"}
product: {2019-1: "3,441", 2018-2: "3,425", 2019-3: "12,975", 2018-4: "11,903"}
product $: {2019-1: "15,448", 2018-2: "$15,114", 2019-3: "$48,966", 2018-4: "$47,338"}
provision for income taxes: {2019-1: "1,677", 2018-2: "1,217", 2019-3: "5,039", 2018-4: "18,096"}
research and development: {2019-1: "4,316", 2018-2: "3,715", 2019-3: "12,363", 2018-4: "10,793"}
revenue:: ""
sales and marketing: {2019-1: "4,565", 2018-2: "4,335", 2019-3: "13,251", 2018-4: "12,709"}
service and other: {2019-1: "6,729", 2018-2: "5,844", 2019-3: "19,523", 2018-4: "16,708"}
total cost of revenue: {2019-1: "10,170", 2018-2: "9,269", 2019-3: "32,498", 2018-4: "28,611"}
total revenue: {2019-1: "30,571", 2018-2: "26,819", 2019-3: "92,126", 2018-4: "80,275"}
weighted average shares outstanding:: ""
```

I tried changing the interface around a bit, but still no dice. The error I receive when using *ngFor in my html is:

```
Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
```

UPDATE JSON List

I believe this is the correct output I'm looking for.

```
{list: {…}}
list:
basic: {2019-1: "7,672", 2018-2: "7,698", 2019-3: "7,679", 2018-4: "7,706"}
basic $: {2019-1: "1.15", 2018-2: "$0.96", 2019-3: "$3.39", 2018-4: "$1.00"}
cost of revenue:: {}
diluted: {2019-1: "7,744", 2018-2: "7,794", 2019-3: "7,759", 2018-4: "7,798"}
diluted $: {2019-1: "1.14", 2018-2: "$0.95", 2019-3: "$3.36", 2018-4: "$0.99"}
earnings per share:: {}
general and administrative: {2019-1: "1,179", 2018-2: "1,208", 2019-3: "3,460", 2018-4: "3,483"}
gross margin: {2019-1: "20,401", 2018-2: "17,550", 2019-3: "59,628", 2018-4: "51,664"}
income before income taxes: {2019-1: "10,486", 2018-2: "8,641", 2019-3: "31,092", 2018-4: "25,794"}
net income $: {2019-1: "8,809", 2018-2: "$7,424", 2019-3: "$26,053", 2018-4: "$7,698"}
operating income: {2019-1: "10,341", 2018-2: "8,292", 2019-3: "30,554", 2018-4: "24,679"}
other income, net: {2019-1: "145", 2018-2: "349", 2019-3: "538", 2018-4: "1,115"}
product: {2019-1: "3,441", 2018-2: "3,425", 2019-3: "12,975", 2018-4: "11,903"}
product $: {2019-1: "15,448", 2018-2: "$15,114", 2019-3: "$48,966", 2018-4: "$47,338"}
provision for income taxes: {2019-1: "1,677", 2018-2: "1,217", 2019-3: "5,039", 2018-4: "18,096"}
research and development: {2019-1: "4,316", 2018-2: "3,715", 2019-3: "12,363", 2018-4: "10,793"}
revenue:: {}
sales and marketing: {2019-1: "4,565", 2018-2: "4,335", 2019-3: "13,251", 2018-4: "12,709"}
service and other: {2019-1: "6,729", 2018-2: "5,844", 2019-3: "19,523", 2018-4: "16,708"}
total cost of revenue: {2019-1: "10,170", 2018-2: "9,269", 2019-3: "32,498", 2018-4: "28,611"}
total revenue: {2019-1: "30,571", 2018-2: "26,819", 2019-3: "92,126", 2018-4: "80,275"}
weighted average shares outstanding:: {}
```

Comment: Well, data doesn't seem to be an array. So you can't iterate over it. Why do you think it is (or should be) an array?

Answer (score 0):

That is not an array you're showing in your result.
 Actually, some parts are not even valid JSON so you may want to check your backend/API how it formats the data.

Understand that TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript and after compilation has no leftover artifacts in your resulting code. TypeScript only helps you prevent mistakes and spot errors in your code, before you compile it. So changing the `interface` on your TypeScript will in no way affect the data received.

If you get valid JSON in, you can use tools to generate valid `TypeScript` `interfaces` and `classes` which you can then use to program with. A good one is `jsontoTS`.

If you update your question with valid JSON data from your backend, let me know; I  may be able to give you some more pointers on where to look and what could be good practices.

Comment: Ah I see which parts make it invalid JSON. Basically the ones that are empty arrays

Comment: If you can fix that and update your question with new data and interfaces; send me a message. I'd happily take a look again!

Comment: @CgOnvMM It seems there is **NO** array in the data you showed us. Only an object containing objects.

Comment: Hmm ok, see what you all are saying. It's a mistake in my python code. 

What if instead, I iterate through each object in the JSON response and add it to the array?

Comment: I would suggest you adhere to web standards, JSON is a web standard. There's no reason to create another data structure when a perfectly well formatted `object` with `arrays` will do. I would recommend updating your Python code on the backend. 

Do you understand how TypeScript comes into play here and that it's just a reflection of what to expect, but that it does not at all do any transformation for you? You can transform incoming data yourself, but TypeScript will not do this for you.

Comment: Also, if you make your code work properly and output valid JSON in `Object` or `Array` form, the `ngFor` directive will start working; as you're passing it an iterable. Right now, in its current form; it looks more like a `Map` and not even a valid one at that. Maybe take a look at finding a way to let Python handle the JSON output for you, instead of manually scripting that?

Comment: Ok I think I fixed it. Each object is an item in the "list".

Also this is valid, "weighted average shares outstanding:" : "{}"

just didn't want there to be a misunderstanding.

Comment: But to me this still seems like the same thing. All I did was add the original JSON object to another JSON object.

Comment: Got it working as intended. Major big kudos for http://www.jsontots.com/ . Pretty big help

Comment: You're welcome, feel free to mark the answer as completed and/or update your question. :-)

Answer (score -1):

your data receive is an object not an array so *ngFor can't use it. To fix this try:

```
ngOnInit() {
this.jsonService.getData().subscribe(data => {
  this.newData = [data];
  console.log(data);
  })
}
```

But it seems you have a architecture problem, because your interface and your api data don't match